# How to create a timer callback that can edit its state object?

Tags: c#, image, timer, reference

I have a `System.Threading.Timer` that receives some data each second, and I want its callback to put the received data into an object, which should be returned to client code. I tried to implement that using C#'s reference types mechanism. Here's the current callback:

```cs
private void Receive(object? obj) {
  var data = GetData();

  obj = (object)data; // Does nothing
}
```

And here's the method that starts the timer (`timer` is a field):

```cs
public void Start(Image image) {
  timer = new Timer(
    Receive,
    image,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
  );
}
```

**Expected behavior**: each second the data (which is image data) is received and put to the image, the reference to which is specified in parameter `image`.

**Actual behavior**: when I defined a variable of type `Image`, passed it to the `Start` method and checked its value (using the Visual Studio debugger) after 5 seconds, it was the empty `Bitmap` I assigned to it at the very start.

I have also checked that the data (containing non-empty image) is sent properly.

Can anybody tell me what's the issue, *or, alternatively, suggest a different way to change the "state" object in a timer callback*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj = (object)data;` only sets the data locally in the `Receive` method. You could fix it by creating a wrapper object

```cs
public class ImageData
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a static instance of it that can be accessed from where you need it

```cs
public static readonly ImageData Data = new ImageData();
```

Depending on where you must access the images it can also an instance member and be private; however, it must always be the same instance that you used to start the timer.

Then start like this

```cs
public void Start() {
  timer = new Timer(
    Receive,
    Data,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
  );
}
```

And receive

```cs
private void Receive(object? obj) {
  var data = (ImageData)obj;  
  data.Image = GetData();
}
```

Now, you can access the new images through the static `Data.Image` property.

---

Alternatively, you could "consume" the image (i.e., display or whatever you are doing with it) directly in the `Receive` callback and ignore the `obj` parameter. However, I do not have enough context information (where do the different code pieces reside and in which thread are they executed, etc.).

---

**Update**

The Image will be `null` in `ImageData` first, until the Receiver callback is called for the first time.

If you want an image at the very start, you can do several things.

1. Start the timer with the first time argument as 0 (this is the time it waits until firing the first time).
2. Call the callback directly in `Start`: `Receive(Data)`.
3. Assign an image with `Data.Image = GetData();`.
4. Initialize the image in `ImageData` with a dummy image (maybe some kind of wait image).

---

**Update 2**

Apparently you are creating a library. I assume the library will pull images regularly and make them available to a consumer.

I suggest exposing an event in the library any consumer can subscribe to to receive images.

In the library we declare event arguments as

```cs
public class UpdateImageEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public UpdateImageEventArgs(Image image)
    {
        Image = image;
    }

    public Image Image { get; }
}
```

A possible implementation of the library:

```cs
public class Library : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<UpdateImageEventArgs>? ImageUpdated;

    private System.Threading.Timer? _timer;

    public void Start()
    {
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Receive, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    private void Receive(object? obj)
    {
        var image = GetImage();
        ImageUpdated?.Invoke(this, new UpdateImageEventArgs(image));
    }

    private static Image GetImage()
    {
        // TODO: Add your implementation
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_timer != null) {
            _timer.Dispose();
            _timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer code:

```cs
public static void Test()
{
    var library = new Library();
    library.ImageUpdated += Library_ImageUpdated;
    library.Start();
}

private static void Library_ImageUpdated(object? sender, UpdateImageEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomethingWith(e.Image);
}
```

If you want to stop the timer, you can do so by calling `library.Dispose();`. This also ensures that the timer resources are disposed properly.

Comment: Instead of the `ImageData`, you could use the built-in [`StrongBox<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.strongbox-1).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'd not use type from `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` in general-purpose code. It even has description: "This type is provided for use by the dynamic methods that the internal expression compiler component of the expression tree API generates."

Comment: It feels a bit confusing to mention static variable. Would be more clear to just replace `Image` with `ImageData` in `public void Start(Image image)` timer callback.

Comment: Nah, it's OK. You are surely using the [`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult) for tasks, which is in the same namespace. The `StrongBox<T>` is a class with a single mutable field, and no logic. I can't see anything bad happening by using it.

Comment: Didn't work. The standard `ImageData` constructor sets `Image` to `null`, and I see that `null` when I read it.

Comment: @SNBS, it looks like you want to set the image in the receiver with `GetData()` and return it back through the `obj` parameter which is a `Imagedata`. So the `Image` will be null in `ImageData` first, until the `Receiver` callback is called for the first time. From then on it will always contain the last image assigned.

Comment: If you say I should ensure `Receive` is called at least once — that's true, and I read the image from `ImageData` after that. As you can see, my timer calls its callback each second, and my main thread sleeps for 3 seconds before reading. And I put `Console.WriteLine("Elapsed")` into the callback. It wrote "Elapsed" three times.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but I can't "consume" the image in `Receive` method because I'm writing a class library (it's now a console application, to make tests easier, but the release will be a library). The image should be returned to client code.

Comment: @SNBS the question says nothing about you writing a class library, and needing to return the image to the client code. The question asks how to store the image into the state of the `Timer`. Which is pointless, because the state is inaccessible outside of the event handler, but that's what you have asked. And Olivier's answer is to the point. If you want to know something else, I would suggest to ask a new question, because this question has been answered.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias No, this question isn't answered. I have said in one of my comments on this answer that the `Image` property in my `ImageData` remains `null` (which was assigned to it by the standard `ImageData` constructor). I have updated my question to mention class library and client code.

Comment: The point is that we do not know who does what. Where is the callback? In the library or in the consumer's code? Or in other words: Does the library get the image and pass it to the consumer or does the consumer get the image (where the library would only provide the timer?

Comment: Using events worked for me, thanks! (Strange that I didn't remember them myself.) And thanks again for such a detailed answer. Awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

In the Recieve method you get an obj as input reference. Then you try to set a value to obj. This last step cannot work, since you work on the reference.
The only way it could work is, if the input reference is given as a ref, which is

```
private void Receive(ref object? obj) {}
```

Passing a reference type by reference enables the called method to replace the object to which the reference parameter refers in the caller.

Comment: It doesn't work because of the `TimerCallback` delegate. It defines a plain `object` parameter (not reference).